# PHP: What is expected -- an html or image?

Tags: php, html

Let's assume I have a script `http://www.example.com/script.php` in my web server. It can be invoked by a client on an html page in two ways, say, like this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/script.php">What does this script do?</a>
```

or this:

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/script.php">
```

In the first variant, a text is expected, in the second -- an image.

If I knew what is expected, I would use different headers in my script, for example,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

for a text and

```
header ("Content-type: image/png");
```

for an image. If I need to output, say, an error `$message`, I would use

```
echo $message;
```

or

```
ImageString($myImage, $font, 0, 0, $message, $black);
ImagePNG($myImage);
```

that is: an image of the message, respectively.

Is it possibly to query the server of what kind of output is expected by the client?

Comment: You can add `?type=image` to the URL. But why don't you just create a file that only handles images (something like `page.php` and `image.php`)? Handling both in the same file only creates a problem where none need be. You could also just link directly to images, if they are not created on-the-fly.

Comment: should this really be one file and not two?

Comment: Yes, the image must be built at runtime, and I use the same script since the handling is mostly the same both for the image and link. As to the usage of a parameter, please see my answer to Timur below. This answers your question, @Dagon, too.

Comment: doesn't explain to why you don't use 2 files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume the question requires EXACTLY the same URL calling the PHP script for different content.

You can determine it base on:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']
```

For example, browser request web page with

```
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

and images with:

```
image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5
```

Different browser send different Accept header, but you should be able to tell whether it wants some text or an image.

Comment: This is the answer I might have come up with if I had to do it myself. I figured there would be something in `$_SERVER` that would differentiate. :-D

Answer (score 2):

Add parameter to address:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/script.php?format=text">What does this script do?</a>

<img src="http://www.example.com/script.php?format=image">
```

Comment: OK, my script expects this parameter, and I expect people invoking the script to properly set it. But what if they miss it or use improperly? I cannot control them, so I want to notify them of their error.

Comment: you can add this in the script.php... if($_GET['format'] == ""){ echo "some error";}

Comment: or just use a default value in case that $_GET['format'] is not specified or improper, eg:make it 'format = text' by default

Comment: If the script is used for an `<image ...>`, `echo` will never be seen by the client.

Comment: The question is asking for differentiating the request, not changing the request to make it differentiated.

Comment: @AlexK I still think that using one file for both requests is a bad architecture. Outputting text and image is really not same thing anyway and you always can move common code to service/model/root controller/etc. May be in your situation the solution is really different and you don't need, for example, to check type at all, but you not provided concrete case.

Answer (score 0):

Create another file for each purpose. Have one file named `text.php` and another named `image.php`. That way, it's specific for each use and will cause less headaches and may even be simpler for the average guy to understand, rather than using a parameter and all that jazz.